# Write eth address to file

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I need to generate several hundred addresses with eth keys and write them to a file, but only iteration numbers are written to the file, what's the problem?

```
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  fs.appendFileSync('accounts.txt', keys.push(accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because you are saving to the file the index of the element that's being pushed to `keys` and not the actual address. Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i+=1) {
    var account = accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
    keys.push(account);
    fs.appendFileSync('accounts.txt', account.address + ',\n');
}
```

Or if you want to save all properties of the `account` object you could do:

`fs.appendFileSync('accounts.txt', JSON.stringify(account) + ',\n');`

But have in mind `account` object also includes property `privateKey` and you might wanna secure that a bit more.